# How to automate the drag and drop action in protractor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, selenium, protractor

Actually I am trying to automate a web app having a drag and drop feature.
I am trying to run the below code to achieve

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(e1, e2).perform();
```

and I'm getting following error

> error: Failed: HTTP method not allowed

Comment: Try: `browser.actions().dragAndDrop(e1,e2).mouseUp().perform();`

Comment: Already tried this method but got same error.

Comment: what i think when it call an action API then this error is appearing

Comment: This is not a solution yet but can you try any other actions? (https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions). Also how is DnD implemented on your page? Is it native HTML5 DnD?

Comment: The page is in HTML5 but DnD is not. also i have tried to do with selenium web-driver in java its working fine there but in protractor its not

Answer (score 1):

You can use external library : [HTML Drag and Drop Simulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd)
for me it is working